# objective-c scrollView zoom image

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageview, scrollview

I try set position image on center scrollView and when zooming scroll not was outside image 
 if the height and width imageView is equal scrollView when zoom and move scroll going outside image.

if imageView height and width set height and width image it's works, but image position top, but not in center.

`self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);`

and if center imageView set scrollView center, position the image will be in the center, but if start zoomed scroll moves up and make impossible move down to the bottom of the image

`self.imageView.center = self.scrollView.center;`

sorry for my english

Comment: i dont understand please explain more ad tell precisely what you are trying to achive and what the problem is

Comment: if use zoom, and size imageView equal scrollView, scrollView leave image edge. I understand why it happens. I tried to set the imageView size of the image, then imageView set position top. i set imageView position center but scroll leave image edge again